# Set correct node path in $PATH

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, npm, amazon-lightsail

I am running a AWS Lightsail instance with NodeJS v14.x. My website runs on NodeJS v18.x. So I installed `nvm` and right now the default Node version is 18.x. `node -v` shows 18.x.
So far good.

When I executed the build command `npm run build`, its throwing error. On checking the error logs I found the the previous node version is being used (v14.x)

From error logs

```
1 verbose cli   '/opt/bitnami/node/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/opt/bitnami/node/bin/npm',
```

So the old path is taking. `echo $PATH` outputs this?

```
/home/bitnami/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin:/opt/bitnami/apache/bin:/opt/bitnami/apache2
/bin:/opt/bitnami/common/bin:/opt/bitnami/git/bin:/opt/bitnami/gonit/bin:/opt/bitnami/mong
odb/bin:/opt/bitnami/node/bin:/opt/bitnami/python/bin:/opt/bitnami/nami/bin:/opt/bitnami/a
pache/bin:/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin:/opt/bitnami/common/bin:/opt/bitnami/git/bin:/opt/bitna
mi/gonit/bin:/opt/bitnami/mongodb/bin:/opt/bitnami/node/bin:/opt/bitnami/python/bin:/opt/b
itnami/nami/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Both node paths are in the $PATH, I only need node version `18.16.0`. Any way to fix this?